# tomcat use pc name, page display changed

Tags: tomcat

why when i access webpage inside tomcat,

if i use localhost:8080 the page is properly displayed. then when i access same page but with pcname:8080 the page display isnt like expected like the css changed?

one example:
looking into css of tomcat login page.

localhost:8080

`UL {
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; LIST-STYLE-TYPE: none; TEXT-INDENT: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0.25em; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; LIST-STYLE-IMAGE: none; PADDING-TOP: 0px
}`

pcname:8080

`UL {
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; LIST-STYLE-TYPE: none; TEXT-INDENT: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0.25em; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px
}`

get the difference > `LIST-STYLE-IMAGE: none;` is absent when using pcname:8080 url.

Answer (score 0):

found some hints : If you are using IE8, the issue may be its Compatibility View. By default, sites in your local intranet - but NOT localhost - are rendered in IE7 compatibility view.

ref:
https://serverfault.com/a/195470